# calculating an Earthquake fault depth

Tags: fault, depth

I'm looking for a simple way to calculate the depth of an earthquake fault , I've searched a lot and it's all bout advanced new researches . I have found something that might be helpful :

"This time interval, pP-P (pP minus P), is used to compute depth-of-focus tables. Using the time difference of pP-P as read from the seismogram and the distance between the epicenter and the seismograph station, the depth of the earthquake can be determined from published travel-time curves or depth tables."

is there any idea of the way of doing this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers site about programming](http://stackoverflow.com/). You seem to be at the modeling stage, not yet at the programming stage, so I don't think your question is on-topic here. There is a [proposal for an associated site about geology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17859/geology?referrer=qD-EoQNsUrqxy83zuoB7dg2) which you may be interested in; that site not open yet, it's still in its early definition phase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need travel-time curve or depth tables, which you will find in specialized books. Then calculate  pP-P, and give the distance from the epicenter, you read on the curve of the table the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taup. the app show travel time and path for a lot of earthquake phases. to reduce error, use phases that have straight or near straight path.